# US Visa is stamped on new passport but has old passport number

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

During my F1 visa application process, I was asked to get a new passport by the visa officer. So I got a new one made and had to submit both new and old passports for stamping. They correctly stamped my F1 visa in my new passport but it has my old passport number written on it.

Will it be a problem for US Customs and Immigration at any port of entry if I carry both my passports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, perhaps not. Might depend on the immigration officer's mood the day you attempt to enter.

I'd return to the visa officer and request that a new vignette be attached reflecting the correct, current passport number.

Comment: "I'd return to the visa officer" How do you propose doing that? You can't just waltz into the embassy.

Comment: The OP had prior contact, knows the location, and might know a name or even have direct contact information. The OP might be able to present it by email, regular post, telephone, or hand-delivery to the Embassy guard. A request might be successful. Because no one knows what the immigration office at the border will do, trying to fix the error beforehand seems a reasonable course of action.

Comment: I agree that trying to fix the problem before arriving at the border is the best idea. However, when I applied for a US visa, I never had any contact information beyond filling in the web application form, and certainly never knew anybody's name. The embassy security staff aren't going to accept hand-delivered mail: that's a distraction from their actual job.

Comment: The Embassy or Consulate will receive postal mail, and might read it, and might act. If the OP doesn't try, then the decision will be made by the immigration officer at the border.

Comment: Agreed. And a telephone call, email or letter are worth trying. But your other suggestions are so implausible that there's no point trying them.

Comment: Every US embassy and consulate has published contact information. Some even have dedicated contact forms for reporting errors in visas. Check the embassy or consulate web site for the country where you received the visa.

Comment: Thank you, I got in touch with the consulate via email and they agreed to get it corrected.